# How can i test app with thinking sphinx with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have Ruby on Rails 3.1 application and i use for Sphinx + Thinking sphinx for searching. For testing i use RSpec + autotest. I want to test my searching. Where can i read how to test my app right via rspec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not what i actually wanted but:

http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/testing.html

Hope, it will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled a [gem](https://github.com/fuzzyalej/thinking-sphinx-rspec-matchers) that helps with the testing process. It is working but needs some love and attention also! :D